# Where is the restart icon in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2008 I often used the "restart" button but it is missing in Visual Studio 2010, at least in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express, I assume it's the same in the standard version as well.

**Where is the restart icon in Visual Studio 2010?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1tjdgv7.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/1tjdgv7.png)

## Added:

Ok, I was able to add it in "Customize", but after adding it, it is greyed out so I can't use it. Close Visual Studio and opened again, still greyed out. **How can I enable it so that I can use it?**

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/bja4fv.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/bja4fv.png)

Comment: I hate this button and thank the maker it's been removed by default.  I've hit that instead of stop so many times I turn blue just seeing it.

Comment: It's still there -- there are just other buttons obscuring it by default (if you let that toolbar get wider it will show up)

Comment: By the way, it's called restart.

Comment: @slaks thansk fixed that

Comment: @billyoneal it doesn't seem to be in the overflow section either (posted image above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Debug toolbar doesn't look like mine.  No problem, you can change it.  Tools + Customize, Commands tab, click Toolbar radio, select "Debug".  Select the location where you want to insert the button.  Click Add Command, select Debug + Restart.

Answer (score 3):

Buttons, who needs buttons?

Ctrl + Shift + F5

[More keyboard shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough room in the Debug toolbar to show all of the buttons, so the restart button moved to the overflow panel.

If you move the toolbars such that there is enough room, the button should appear.

Comment: And if it's still not there, you can always add it.

Comment: @michaelburr thanks, I used customize to add it, but it is greyed out, any idea how I can enable it so I can use it?

Comment: It will only be enabled while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The restart icon is in the toolbar in the Ultimate edition, so I guess you don't have enough room in the toolbar...or somehow it got magically disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The "stop" button is grayed out so I guess your program is not running. You can only use the restart button when a program is running inside the debugger.